# Using regex to add leading zeroes

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I would like to add a certain number of leading zeroes (say up to 3) to all numbers of a string. For example:

Input: `/2009/5/song 01 of 12`

Output: `/2009/0005/song 0001 of 0012`

What's the best way to do this with regular expressions?

**Edit:**

I picked the first correct answer. However, all answers are worth giving a read.

Comment: First you need to split text into components using regex (words/numbers) then use number formatting to add leading zeros.

Comment: Thanks serg555. Why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use something that supports a callback so you can process the match:

```
>>> r=re.compile(r'(?:^|(?<=[^0-9]))([0-9]{1,3})(?=$|[^0-9])')
>>> r.sub(lambda x: '%04d' % (int(x.group(1)),), 'dfbg345gf345', sys.maxint)
'dfbg0345gf0345'
>>> r.sub(lambda x: '%04d' % (int(x.group(1)),), '1x11x111x', sys.maxint)
'0001x0011x0111x'
>>> r.sub(lambda x: '%04d' % (int(x.group(1)),), 'x1x11x111x', sys.maxint)
'x0001x0011x0111x'
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. Not possible without using callbacks?

Comment: It may be possible with a sufficiently-complex regular expression or with multiple regular expressions, but unless function calls are ludicrously expensive this method will be faster.

Answer (score 29):

In Perl:

```
s/([0-9]+)/sprintf('%04d',$1)/ge;
```

Comment: Makes me want to learn Pearl after comparing it to my Java implementation.

Answer (score 4):

A sample:

```
>>> re.sub("(?<!\d)0*(\d{1,3})(?!\d)","000\\1","/2009/5/song 01 of 3")
'/2009/0005/song 0001 of 0003'
```

Note:

- It only works for numbers 1 - 9 for now
- It is not well test yet

I can't think of a single regex without using callbacks for now* (there might be a way to do it).

Here are two regular expression to process that:

```
>>> x = "1/2009/5/song 01 of 3 10 100 010 120 1200 abcd"
>>>
>>> x = re.sub("(?<!\d)0*(\d{1,3})(?!\d)","000\\1",x)
#'0001/2009/0005/song 0001 of 0003 00010 000100 00010 000120 1200 abcd'
>>>
>>> re.sub("0+(\d{4})(?!\d)","\\1",x) #strip extra leading zeroes
'0001/2009/0005/song 0001 of 0003 0010 0100 0010 0120 1200 abcd'
```

Comment: @kovpas, yeah, under thinking. thats a bit difficult without using callbacks, because filling 0 is variable length.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, S.Mark. Changed the example to challenge your solution.

Comment: I added 2 regexes but I will try to get it with single regex, there should be way to do it.

Comment: looks like my regex skill failed to achieve that. couldn't figure out :(

Answer (score 2):

Using `c#`:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\d+", me =>
{
    return int.Parse(me.Value).ToString("0000");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
>>> x
'/2009/5/song 01 of 12'
>>> ''.join([i.isdigit() and i.zfill(4) or i for i in re.split("(?<!\d)(\d+)(?!\d)",x)])
'/2009/0005/song 0001 of 0012'
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> x
'/2009/5/song 01 of 12'
>>> r=re.split("(?<!\d)(\d+)(?!\d)",x)
>>> ''.join(a+b.zfill(4) for a,b in zip(r[::2],r[1::2]))
'/2009/0005/song 0001 of 0012'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your regular expression implementation does not support look-behind and/or look-ahead assertions, you can also use this regular expression:

```
(^|\D)\d{1,3}(\D|$)
```

And replace the match with `$1 + padLeft($2, 4, "0") + $3` where `$1` is the match of the first group and `padLeft(str, length, padding)` is a function that prefixes `str` with `padding` until the length `length` is reached.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>`<warning>` This assumes academic interest, of course you should use callbacks to do it clearly and correctly `</warning>`</sup>

I'm able to abuse regular expressions to have **two** leading zeros (.NET flavor):

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @".(?=\b\d\b)|(?=\b\d{1,2}\b)", "$&0");
```

It doesn't work if there's a number in the beginning of the string. This works by matching the 0-width before a number or the character before a number, and replacing them with 0.

I had no luck expanding it to three leading zeros, and certainly not more.

Answer (score 1):

**The principle**: Two replaces in first you add zeros front of that in the second you cut last x places. This worked for my solution to this issue in SQL. Solution of my problem that I solved.

**The example**:
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(version,'.*([0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*)..*','\1.00000\2'),'([0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.][0-9]*[.]).*(.....$)','\1\2'),'.','')

this code makes the value 1.1.1.1 => 1.1.1.00001

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl solution without callbacks or recursion. It does use the Perl regex extension of execution of code in lieu of the straight substitution (the `e` switch) but this is very easily extended to other languages that lack that construct.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   print "string:\t\t\t$_\n";
# uncomment if you care about 0000000 case:
#   s/(^|[^\d])0+([\d])/\1\2/g;
#   print "now no leading zeros:\t$_\n";    
   s/(^|[^\d]{1,3})([\d]{1,3})($|[^\d]{1,3})/sprintf "%s%04i%s",$1,$i=$2,$3/ge;
   print "up to 3 leading zeros:\t$_\n";
}
print "\n";

__DATA__
/2009/5/song 01 of 12
/2010/10/song 50 of 99
/99/0/song 1 of 1000
1
01
001
0001
/001/
"02"
0000000000
```

Output:

```
string:                /2009/5/song 01 of 12
up to 3 leading zeros:  /2009/0005/song 0001 of 0012
string:                /2010/10/song 50 of 99
up to 3 leading zeros:  /2010/0010/song 0050 of 0099
string:                /99/0/song 1 of 1000
up to 3 leading zeros:  /0099/0/song 0001 of 1000
string:                1
up to 3 leading zeros:  0001
string:                01
up to 3 leading zeros:  0001
string:                001
up to 3 leading zeros:  0001
string:                0001
up to 3 leading zeros:  0001
string:                /001/
up to 3 leading zeros:  /0001/
string:                "02"
up to 3 leading zeros:  "0002"
string:                0000000000
up to 3 leading zeros:  0000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Combined in Xcode:

```
targetName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05d",number];
```

Gives 00123 for number 123

Answer (score 0):

A valid Scala program to replace all groups of n digits to 4. `$$` escapes the line ending char `$`, because we are using [StringContext](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/scala/StringContext.html) (string prefixed by s).

```
  (f/:(1 to 3)){case (res,i) =>
     res.replaceAll(s"""(?<=[^\\d]|^)(\\d$i)(?=[^\\d]|$$)""", "0"*(4-i)+"$1")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

C# version

```
        string input = "/2009/5/song 01 of 12";
        string regExPattern = @"(\/\d{4}\/)(\d+)(\/song\s+)(\d+)(\s+of\s+)(\d+)";
        string output = Regex.Replace(input, regExPattern, callback =>
        {
            string yearPrefix = callback.Groups[1].Value;
            string digit1 = int.Parse(callback.Groups[2].Value).ToString("0000");
            string songText = callback.Groups[3].Value;
            string digit2 = int.Parse(callback.Groups[4].Value).ToString("0000");
            string ofText = callback.Groups[5].Value;
            string digit3 = int.Parse(callback.Groups[6].Value).ToString("0000");
            return $"{yearPrefix}{digit1}{songText}{digit2}{ofText}{digit3}";
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested in how to do this in R, the package `stringr` is helpful:

```
library(stringr)
input<-"/2009/5/song 01 of 12"
str_replace_all(string = input,
                pattern="((?<![0-9])[0-9]*([0-9]{1,3}))",
                replacement=function(x){str_pad(x,width=4,side="left",pad="0")})

"/2009/0005/song 0001 of 0012"
```

See: https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf